# What is the right type definition to use for the onChange event for Grommet's RangeInput component?

Tags: typescript, grommet

I'm getting a typescript error for `onChange` of Grommet's `RangeInput` component.

```
<RangeInput
 onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
  setAge(event.target.value)
 }
/>
```

Error:

```
Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<Element>) => void) & ((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void)'.
  Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<Element>) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
      Type 'ChangeEvent<Element>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
        Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 159 more.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(8, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RangeInputProps & ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & { ...; }'
```

What is the right type to use for the onChange? React.ChangeEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the types of `grommet`, see https://github.com/grommet/grommet/blob/2a38c185e1/src/js/components/RangeInput/index.d.ts#L8.

The type of `onChange` omits generic param `T`, that means the typeof `onChange` is `(event: React.ChangeEvent<Element>) => void`.

A simple way to resolve this problem is use `as` in your project:

```js
<RangeInput
 onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent) =>
  setAge((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
 }
/>
```

A better way is create a pr for `grommet` to fix this problem, just need to remove the line of `onChange` declaration.